# Accounts.validateNewUser not displaying proper user values

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor and trying to do a simple user validation and i keep getting undefined for my custom validation

here is my code

```
 Template.registration.events({
        'submit #new_user': function(event){
            var user;
            var email   = $('[name=email]').val()
            var password = $('[name=password]').val()
            user = {
                email: email,
                password: password
            }
            event.preventDefault()
            Accounts.createUser(user,
            function(error){
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                } else {
                   /* Router.go('/')*/
                }

            });
        }

    })


Accounts.validateNewUser(function (user){
        console.log('user is' user.email)
        return true;
})
```

when i create a user with valid data it works but when i try to pass some invalid data to test the validation i get undefined for the user.email. After inspecting the log i noticed that there is no email value being passed.

This is my log output

```
user is{"createdAt":"2015-09-15T08:54:09.836Z","_id":"23ZjwtNTPsv2pSRrg","services":{"password":{"bcrypt":"$2a$10$uPbyiNo5Bz25j8TV6vyGteNEtOT3tjm6iisu0TbS0FDN6InMJWeTa"}},"emails":[{"address":"loslls@fkdf.com","verified":false}]}
```

How can i get this to work just like in the doc were i can call user.email

Comment: `user.emails[0].address`? It's right there in your console output.

Comment: @DavidWeldon what about the passworrd. will it validate it as it has been encrypted. As i will like to validate the length of password

Comment: This has been covered in other questions - you have to validate it on the client. The server never sees a plaintext password.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Tried using the validation on the client and got `Uncaught TypeError: Accounts.validateNewUser is not a function`

Comment: You need to validate it before creating an user. After Accounts.createUser() is called password is being encrypted and you won't see it in plain text anymore according to http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser

Comment: You literally have to look at the value of `$('[name=password]').val()` and check if its meets your requirements.